# Selecting points shapefile by raster values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, shapefile

I have a shapefile point (with 200 points record) and a raster image (with 5 classes). I want to select points that fall within a specific class of the raster image. For example, I want to select points that fall within class 2. I am using ArcGIS 10.7

I have tried to use select by attributes, intersect tools or zonal statistics but they do not solve my problem.

Attached is a picture of the data (red dots are the points)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**"Extract Values to Points" (Spatial Analyst license)**](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm) to extract the raster values to a new point layer. Select the points from this layer based on the needed raster value that is given in a new column.

If you use discrete classes like land-use, select `none` as interpolation method.